# Non-resolvable parent POM in new Spring Starter Project using corporate proxy

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, parent-pom

I just started using STS and the previous answers I have looked through does not have an answer to my question.

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for learn.fullstack.ngspring:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 
Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.8.RELEASE from 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could 
not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.8.RELEASE from/to 
central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path 
building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid 
certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
```

1) I configured proxy settings under Preferences -> Network Connections, which allows me to create a Spring Starter Project

2) I am unable to run any mvn commands

3) I created a settings.xml with my own corporate credentials:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
     <proxies>
       <proxy>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>http</protocol>
          <host>XXXXXX</host>
          <port>XX</port>
          <username>XXXXXXX</username>
          <password>XXXXXXX</password>
        </proxy>
      </proxies>
    </settings>
```

Unable to work after doing these two steps. My questions are:

1) Do I need to make any changes to the pom.xml file?

2) Where can I find 'local POM' or direct STS to point to the local POM?

Comment: First of all you don't need to edit your pom.xml, And than I think you are using nexus within the company and you are having problems accessing spring repos or your maven settings.xml nexus server url definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Your protocol is setting the proxy for `http`, you'll also need a `https` proxy in there, `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2`

Answer (score 0):

Select window option in Eclipse and go to preferences and then go to Maven and there update .setting file and change proxy username or password as of ur system.
Then Go to Project ,right click and then Select Maven and update Project

Answer (score 0):

Try with removing all files and directories(settings.xml, repository etc.) from **.m2** folder which is located at C:\Users\username\.m2 and build the project again using mvn clean install.